# How to hide Detail View Controller in UISPlitViewController When Orientation Changes to Landscape

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uisplitviewcontroller, uisplitviewdelegate

I am using `UISplitViewController`, When `UISplitViewController` is in Portrait Mode then first time it is showing only `MasterViewController` in Whole Screen and `DetailViewController` is hidden at this time.

But when i change the orientation from `Portrait` to `landscape` then `detailViewController` is appearing. I want the `detailViewController` to appear only in `Portrait` Mode otherwise it should not appear.